# regex search text1 OR text2

Tags: regex, grep

I am new to regex, how would build a regex to find a pattern that has name1 OR name2 in it.

I.e.,

```
text = 'the lion and the tiger are animals'
```

I would like to build a regular expression that finds if text has the strings lion, OR string tiger in it?

I know that by words you would make [ae] and would find matches or a or e, but for whole words I am not sure.

thanks!

Comment: what regex-flavor are you using?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html!

Comment: What language are you using?  What regex grammar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regexp, the logical OR is `|`. That is to say:

```
lion|tiger
```

So, for example,

```
^.*(lion|tiger).*$
```

Answer (score 2):

Answers so far won't quite work if you want to ensure that "lion" or "tiger" is the full word (i.e. they'll still match something like "footigerbar"). If you want to ensure that it's the *words* "lion" or "tiger," and not just the substrings, something like the following will do it:

```
\b(lion|tiger)\b
```

`\b` denotes a word boundary, which will ensure your regex doesn't match, for example, 'unadsasdeflionasdeafeg' or 'dandelion'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an OR:

```
(lion|tiger)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use "pipe" also need the `-E` option for `grep`

```
grep  -E 'lion|tiger'
```